# Custom Query in Symfony Form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

createQueryBuilder Query Working fine Form, when i try to write custom Query using EntityManager its showing warning. EntityManager  not available.

**Controller :**

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ContractsType($user, $isAdmin, $securityContext), $contract, array('em' => $em, 'referring_student' => $contract->getReferringStudent()));
```

**ContractsType**

```
class ContractsType extends AbstractType {

$queryBuilder = function($repo) use ($user) {

return $repo->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->leftJoin('p.employees', 'e')
    ->where('e.id = :employee_id')
    ->setParameter('employee_id', $user->getId())
    ->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC');
}
  $builder->add('store', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'C2EducateToolsBundle:Stores',
        'label' => 'Center',
        'query_builder' => $queryBuilder,
        'property' => 'name',
        'empty_value' => 'Select')
    );
    }
```

createQueryBuilder working Fine, but I want to write custom Query using EntityManager, How can I make the entity Equery available here. so that I can Run the below Query.

```
$storesQuery = "select store_id as id,ts.name as name from tbl_employees e LEFT JOIN tbl_stores ts ON e.store_id=ts.id where e.id=:employeesId  AND ts.center_type_id!=:centerTypeId AND ts.select_option = :selectOption";
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($storesQuery);
            $stmt->bindValue('employeesId', $user->getId());
            $stmt->execute();
            $listLocations = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: A custom [repository class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html)?

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `$em` by making the [form type a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service).

```
# myBundle\config\services.yml
services:
    form.type.address:
        class: myBundle\Form\AddressType
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'] # We inject our familiar $em.
```

**Meanwhile, in our form type:**

```
// myBundle\Form\AddressType.php
// ...
Class AddressType
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em) // Type-hint so nothing funny gets in.
    {
        $this->em = $em; // And store it on our form type during instantiation.
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ... Then use it in here!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "choices" option for EntityType form, so you just execute query not in query builder but in your form type and result set to choices like

```
$query = ....;
$result = $query->execute();
$builder->add('store', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'C2EducateToolsBundle:Stores',
    'label' => 'Center',
    'choices' => $result,
    'property' => 'name',
    'empty_value' => 'Select')
);
```

Comment: Yes, You are Right, i want to write the query and pass the results, but problem in Entity Manager is not avaible there, how can i configure that.?

Comment: I thought you already use it, because you pass $em in options, so you can get em by $em = $options['em']; Or you can pass em in service like in @Rhono answer